# How to redirect user to YouTube video upon form completion? (HTML5)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, redirect, submit

I'm using `form action="youtubevideolink.com"` with a `method="get"`. When I click 'submit' it instead takes you to youtube's main page, not the video page itself.

Any way to accomplish this via HTML or Vanilla JS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple, keep in mind the URL is a get request already with a variable `v` See this example: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QH2-TGUlwu4`

```html
<form action="https://www.youtube.com/watch" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="v" value="QH2-TGUlwu4">
  <button type="submit">Click Me!!!</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would call a function using the `onsubmit` reference. I would look something like this:

HTML:

```
 <form onsubmit="redirectToYoutube()">
    
 </form>
```

Javascript:

```
function redirectToYoutube() {
  const url = "youtubevideolink.com"
  location.replace(url)
}
```